# How to show MSN contacts in Skype?

Tags: contacts, import, skype

MSN chat has been retired and Skype will be taking its place. What about my contacts on MSN? Should I see them in Skype now, or should I add them one by one?

I remember that the Skype website asked me to migrate from MSN to Skype and I did this, but no contacts were imported into Skype.

Comment: Can you see them when they are online?

Comment: no i can't in all cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Skype`-`Profile`-`Edit your Profile` and make sure that you see your Skype username and also the MSN mail adress under `Accounts`. (Make sure you have the latest Skype version)

Then all your contacts (Skype & MSN) should be available in Skype.

Otherwise **visit the Skype Website and log in with your MSN Account**:
https://secure.skype.com/login
(There you can then merge both accounts)

Comment: I did that and in my Profile it Says that Microsoft Account is linked, but i still can't see my msn contacts.

Comment: @AmrElGarhy - Which means your not logging in with your Microsoft Account.

Answer (score 3):

You need to log into Skype using your MSN email address - and not your Skype address.

If you look at [this article](http://logicum.co/move-wlm-msn-your-contacts-to-skype/), you'll see that at the end of the migration it does tell you this, but it's not very clear.

[image]

Comment: Can you add the source of your info?